# Are there any way to get ecs instance metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metadata, amazon-ecs

From the running aws ecs instances, can I get the detail about its cluster name and container instance ID?

In EC2, I can run below curl command to get its instance id, do I have similar command in ECS?

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer my own question, in AWS ECS cluster, a daemon is running, you can queue its metadata by below commands

```
$ curl http://localhost:51678/v1/tasks | python -mjson.tool


$ curl -s http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata | python -mjson.tool

{
    "Cluster": "application-1",
    "ContainerInstanceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:1234567890:container-instance/ee4d3451d-2de3-4180-b1c6-023ed6e8c343",
    "Version": "Amazon ECS Agent - v1.14.1 (467c3d7)"
}
```

This will be useful if you need to deregister itself from ECS cluster, for example, you use spot instance in ecs cluster.

Refer:

[ecs agent introspection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-introspection.html)

Comment: It seems I can hit http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata from the host instance, not from within the running container.  From the running container, I get "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 51678: Connection refused"

Comment: Try `curl "http://172.17.0.1:51678/v1/tasks?dockerid=${HOSTNAME}"` from within a running Docker container on ECS. The `${HOSTNAME}` is your short Docker container id which filters the task list.

Answer (score 2):

Just to echo what [@per-cederberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087731/per-cederberg) in his comment so it doesn't get buried (and for some free sweet karma ), the *running container* can call `http://172.17.0.1:51678/v1/metadata` to get the same information.